# How to synchronize django production with local code-base without using git?

Tags: django, synchronization

I have a project that is almost finished but needs some tweaks that I first test on local machine. I am wondering apart from using git or uploading new files through ftp, what is the best way to keep the production update with the least hassle?

Comment: "Without using the best way to do it". Why?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just to avoid buying a private git, as a public one is not an option :)

Comment: BitBucket is free as @catavaran states, or use rsync as he also suggests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to avoid buying a private git then use [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/). They offer private repositories for free.

Answer (score 1):

Use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) to mirror project files from you local machine to server.

Comment: Well, rsync is a powerful tool to sync. However I was wondering if there is some python-specific and perhaps more handy tool.